# import .dbf into RStudio: failed on DBF filefseek (-2147207979)

Tags: r, import, dbf

I'm trying to import `.dbf` file into RStudio.

This file is the attribute table of a shapefile that I exported as `.dbf`.
You can find the `.dbf` file in [**this link**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5B6N7WsEfbdU1ozcFlTOTFLYnM?usp=sharing)

I tried importing it as below

```
library(foreign)
df <- read.dbf("5layers1.dbf")
```

I got errors (below) and RStudio crashed so I couldn't get `sessionInfo()`. 
[image]

Any suggestions how to import this large .dbf file into RStudio will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The file is too large for me to test. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Can you include the code you used to export it please?

Comment: @Hugh
I have 4GB RAM

Comment: @TravisHeeter
I haven't exported it using a code from ArcGIS. I just exported it using export as .dbf file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to save it as a csv-file (I did this with `LibreOffice` in one or two hours and use `;` as a separator). After you can import it to `R` like this:

```
dat <- readLines("5layers1.csv")

li <- strsplit(dat, ";")
num <- as.numeric(unlist(lapply(li, `[[`, 100)))

boxplot(num, main=unlist(strsplit(dat[1], ";"))[100])
mtext(side=3, text=paste("n = ", length(num), sep=""))
```

Its really a big file! You will have a lot of fun with this! I'm not sure if R is the tool for this job. I use a Tinkpad T430 with 8GB Ram and it need 2min for run this five lines to make this boxplot, which present one of the 179 attributes of your dbf-file:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. I'm afraid having PC with 4GB RAM won't help me to do it. I think R with my PC is not the right tool to do this exercise.

Comment: You can try. I was quit surprised that i only used 2.26GB for the operation above including the os. If you want I can upload the csv file for you. Than you try if this operation work. If it is possible you try with only a small fraction of the data, to prepare your operations and calculations. and if everything is sown you let R for some hours alone and come back after some hours to see your results :)

Answer (score 1):

For me `read.dbf()` didn't work neither and the files are usually too big to open it in excel to convert them into something more usable. I find a better way to read in .dbf files is to use the dbf ODBC Driver distributed under Windows (usually only 32-bit version), given you operate under Windows, and create a connection together with the `RODBC` and ultimately access the data as in the usual way you connect to a database. Now, one would need to use the 32-bit version of R so it´s compatible with the driver architecture, but R comes with both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the OP, I found that `foreign::read.dbf` crashed my session. However I was able to use the `rio` package without any problems:

`df <- rio::import("5layers1.dbf")`

https://github.com/leeper/rio